# What is the term for a mean character role-played by a nice player?

Tags: character-creation, roleplaying, terminology

Contradictory character seems to mean [a character who defies stereotypes](http://writerunboxed.com/2007/03/26/character-contradictions/) or [exhibits traits that contradict one another](http://www.writingforums.org/showthread.php?t=34537), in a literary sense. I wish to distinguish what I mean from [round characters](http://narrative.georgetown.edu/wiki/index.php/Round_character).

**Is there a commonly used term for when a player role-plays someone radically different than the player is? Or is the ambiguous "contradictory character" as good as it gets?** I'm not interested in potential terms - if there isn't any normally used term for it I'll accept that answer. DMs don't count here because we might role-play almost anyone in a normal game; What about when a player breaks away from their norm and portrays a persona clashingly different from their own?

I'm aware of the relevant psychological terms but alas no clear RPG term.

Comment: You might describe the activity as "playing against type", but I don't know of an accepted term for this in RPGs either.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

TV Tropes calls this situation [**mean character, nice actor**](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MeanCharacterNiceActor) (and vice versa). It's [quite common in the drama world](http://www.g33kwatch.com/movies/story-of-a-five-year-old-avenger-meeting-the-avengers/) but doesn't seem to have an established term beyond *acting.* You sometimes hear *playing against type* for this, although that's more about a difference from your previous roles, not your own personality.

The specific case of an opposite-sex character is a [*crossdresser*](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Crossdresser) or [*gender bender.*](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GenderBender)

Comment: Interesting. Yeah, I like mixing in the concept of typecast but it doesn't seem to quite capture the meaning.
I am familiar with the different gender portrayal. More focused on personality.

Comment: @LitheOhm By the way, I cited TV Tropes because they usually tell you the mainstream name for their tropes where they exist (e.g., a _stable time loop_ is elsewhere known as the _bootstrap paradox_). They note that the trope is very common but _don't_ offer a mainstream name, which I take as evidence of absence.

Comment: It would seem our closest candidate then comes from acting. At least it's closer than the literary round character.

Comment: +1 we use "playing against type" to describe this, it may not be logically correct but... People often play to their personality as their most common type anyway.

Comment: +1, "Playing against type" is the answer that sprang to mind as soon as I read the question title.

Answer (score 2):

The terms I've heard most often are "roleplaying challenge" or a "stretch."

Comment: I've heard "stretch" a few times, usually voiced as, "That character is a real stretch for him, but he's playing him well."

Answer (score 2):

We called it "the Devil's Advocate" character, after the euphemism. One of my friends is really popular with this archetype. He ran a character who rolled such a bad charisma score that he decided to make him a cowardly warrior who couldn't stand the sight of blood. Obviously, while not a great character for combat situations, the gameplay was brilliant and hysterical as one of your sword-swinging companions starts shrieking out like a little-girl "Don't hurt me! Don't hurt me!" (this situation is verbatim).

Having such a polar opposite character (another term; not great, mind you) can be a blessing if the player is all for it, and an *experienced* player. I would not leave this to someone new to RPGs or to the group. Usually the effect is quite humorous, but many times it was a real pain as a quarter of our party was practically useless at everything except bad commentary and stating the painfully obvious.

Our DM created a feat called "Cowards' Cry" (the opposite of a battlecry) in which, if a coward screamed in terror and the attackers failed a Will check, they would be stunned for a number of rounds equal to 1/3 the level of the coward, in awe of the awesome shriek. This actually saved us a time or two, as it was an area-effect feat tailored for that character alone.